# sass problem setting variable using map-get

Tags: sass

I'm trying to override a variable in a 3rd party package using sass (version 1.58.1)and having a problem ... the source code where `$theme` is my map and `map-get($theme, primary)` gives `#107d9f` is as follows.

```scss
.thing {
    --special-foreground-color: map-get($theme, primary);
    color: map-get($theme, primary);
}
```

and results in ...

```css
.thing {
    --special-foreground-color: map-get($theme, primary);
    color: #107d9f;
}
```

Any "standard" attribute gets substituted properly from the map-get() call but not my --var. How can I set this variable using map-get?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just figured it out. I have to wrap it in `#{}`. My source-code should read ...

```scss
.thing {
    --special-foreground-color: #{map-get($theme, primary)};
    color: map-get($theme, primary);
}
```

Still not sure why I have to do that for one and not the other but it works.

Comment: You are mixing SASS and CSS variables for the 1st one.  The 2nd one is pure SASS

Comment: Well I guess I don't understand the nuances of that statement because to me "color: map-get()" is a mix of CSS and SASS. But I guess that's me not understanding SASS too well. Styling is not my forte (obviously) but... :)

Comment: The map-get() is SASS.  Color is a CSS property

Comment: Yes but color: map-get() works it's the other one that doesn't work.

Comment: copy this --special-foreground-color: #{map-get($theme, "primary")}. Notice the "" around primary. Then define the variable under :root. Then you can use it.

Comment: When I say use it, use it as var( --special-foreground-color: #{map-get($theme, "primary")})